# How to build an Android widget that plays video

Tags: java, android, video, stream, widget

I'm wanting to build an Android widget for my phone that streams a video from a link on button click. I've searched tutorials on Google but I'm still having difficulty understanding how I'd achieve this.

Does anybody have an example of something similar to this or know of any good tutorials to get me started?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use android native VideoView. It can even play online streaming videos.